# How to Install MongoDB and Connect to DB with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I had Downloaded and installed the mongo dB And it still showing the error

Please tell me how to configure and connect to MongoDB in PHP

[please check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TtIk.png)

Comment: showing which error?

Comment: Undefined type 'MongoDB\Client'. this is the error

Comment: For PHP you need to install the [Mongo PHP extension](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) and the [PHP Library](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/php-library/current/). Did you follow [MongoDB PHP Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php/)?

Comment: Yes Installed but still it is showing error.

Comment: Could you please check the screenshot I added?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$client = new MongoDB\Client(
    'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-address>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
);
$db = $client->test;
```

[Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php/)

Comment: `mongodb+srv` looks more like MongoDB Atlas, not local installation.

Answer (score 0):

before you connect you want to add a mongo driver for PHP, then you

[reference][1]
[video reference][2]

```
<?PHP
    $m = new MongoClient();
    echo "Connection to database successfully";
?>
```

[1]: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_php.htm#:~:text=%3C%3F-,php%20%2F%2F%20connect%20to%20mongodb%20%24m%20%3D%20new%20MongoClient()%3B%20echo,('%24set'%3D%3E
[2]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSIQ8n6H9os

Comment: I did it, It says "Undefined type 'MongoDB\Client'."

Answer (score 0):

After you completed the installation did you added

```
[extension=mongodb.so]
```

in your `php.ini` file? If no please add this line of code to your `php.ini` file.

**Please note that each OS has different steps to install the driver.**

You can find more info about the PHP driver here
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setup.php

To check if you have installed the driver properly, create a `info.php` in your project folder and add this function `phpinfo();` to your file.

Visit the `info.php` file in your browser and try to find the mongodb module there, you can use this anchor `#module_mongodb` appended to your url to see the module section directly.

If you can’t find nothing there, it means that your MongoDB/PHP driver is not installed/configured properly.